# Prototype's equivalent/alternative to jQuery's ".load()"

Tags: jquery, load, prototype

What's the equivalent/workaround in prototype to jQuery's `.load()` ?

En detail, i have to rewrite this

```
$("#myElement img").load(function() {
```

to Prototype. Please don't punch me, it's my company's decision.

Comment: You’re switching to prototype and you just need to handle the `load` event? Might need to [learn Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/learn/) :)

Comment: http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/ajax/

Comment: The "doc" does not feature anything like that.

Comment: @Panique, `load` is a standard DOM event, so Prototype manages it like all the other standard events. Have a look at [Event.observe()](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Event/observe/).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You are my Hero! Upvote! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself: The best solution (crossbrowsersafe & does not have cache issues) is:

```
// get img element that inside of #motherElementWithAnID
// it's [0] because it's the first (and only) in the result array
var picElement = $("motherElementWithAnID").select("img")[0];

// wait for fully loaded element content
picElement.onload = function() { ... });
```

Comment: by the way: NEVER write `onLoad`. It would be a syntax error. You need `onload`